# Cannot brew link libtool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, imagemagick, libtool

Ive installed imagemagick on Yosemite, but during the installation I got this error...

`Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.2... 
Error: Could not symlink share/info/libtool.info
/usr/local/share/info is not writable.`

I have tried `brew link libtool` but get the same error

I have tried running `brew doctor and brew prune`

What else can I do to try and get this installed correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/share/info && brew doctor
```